# I bought a game from Ubuntu Software Centre, How do I download it for Linux Mint?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, software-installation

I bought the game TRAUMA from the ubuntu software centre, using my login user/password and paid with my debit card, I can download and play the purchased game in ubuntu fine. But I recently switched to Linux Mint, and it's not in the repositories, I looked on the trauma site and it there is no login, or anything, I don't want to pay again :(

Is there any way I can retrieve my purchased game?
Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but since you switched to Linux Mint, that makes this question somewhat off-topic for our site :(.
Linux Mint has diverged from Ubuntu quite a bit, so you would probably be a bit hard pressed to get some of the same features, like paid-for software.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.noobslab.com/2011/12/install-ubuntu-software-center-in-linux.html

check here you may find something to help you!